# Why is the solution to Cinema Seat Allocation considered greedy?

Tags: greedy-algorithms, resource-allocation

[LeetCode problem 1386. Cinema Seat Allocation](https://leetcode.com/problems/cinema-seat-allocation/description/) requires finding the number of 4-person seating groups available (subject to certain constraints) after individual seat reservations have been made. The problem is tagged by LeetCode as Greedy.

The constraints are that there are only 3 permissible 4-person groupings per row of 10 seats:

- left (columns 2-5)
- middle (columns 4-7)
- right (columns 6-9)

Because the middle grouping overlaps with the left and right groupings, at most 2 groupings in a row can be made available.

There is a straightforward solution giving the optimal value:

1. Iterate over the (unsorted) list of prior reservations, each consisting of a row and column, keeping track of which of the 3 permissible 4-person groupings are blocked.
2. Initialize `total` to 2 times the number of rows having no groupings blocked.
3. For each row with blocked groupings, add to `total` the number of nonblocked groupings.
4. Return the total.

Many user-provided solutions are tagged or described as greedy despite following the above algorithm, such as:

- [Greedy Approach](https://leetcode.com/problems/cinema-seat-allocation/solutions/3581453/greedy-approach/)
- [Simple greedy approach](https://leetcode.com/problems/cinema-seat-allocation/solutions/608344/simple-greedy-approach/) [Java]

Why is this solution considered greedy, or is there a different greedy approach that I am missing?

Comment: I agree with you. I did not find this solution greedy. I have seen people using greedy tag for simple trivial solutions.